# Populating a text box from from the value in a drop down

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm creating a form in apex where I want to populate a text box with a value which has been selected in a drop down box. This needs to be done using a select statement on the form.

I have tried using a Dynamic action.

If I was using SQL I would pass the value of the id which I have retrieved using a combo box.

SELECT APPLICATION_ID FROM APPLICATIONS WHERE JOBID = :P55_JOBID

this would update my APEX field (P55_APP_ID)

P55_JOBID is the Job ID APEX field.

The Select statement for APP_ID works but I want it  to be updated when the Job Dropdown list changes. I've been told to use a Dynamic action but I cant work out how it triggers a refresh of App_ID..

thanks for your help,

mike

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question needs a little work - some screenshots showing what you've attempted would help. It's hard to tell what fields are meant to do what. Have you tried the 'Set item' action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a dynamic action that is triggered on the Change event of the select list (P55_JOBID). The action of this will be Set Value and the Set Type will be SQL Statement. Add your SQL (SELECT APPLICATION_ID FROM APPLICATIONS WHERE JOBID = :P55_JOBID) here and then under Page Items to Submit include your select list (P55_JOBID).

The Selection Type will be Item(s) and the Item(s) will be your text area (P55_APP_ID).